# How to slide page out left at Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

**Want to do**

When I transition the page(Activity), I want to add animation like slide out left.

I tried these codes for animation. These have **SlideInLeft** and **SlideOutRight** but don't have **SlideOutLeft**.

```
Bundle animationBundle = ActivityOptions.MakeCustomAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out).ToBundle();
```

and

```
This.OverridePendingTransition(Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft, Android.Resource.Animation.SlideOutRight);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a folder named `anim` below the `Resources` folder, and then create a `slide_out_left.xml` in it, such as:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

And then use it in the `This.OverridePendingTransition(Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft, Resource.Animation.slide_out_left);`

For more information, you can refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923422/missing-slide-in-right-and-slide-out-left-animations-in-android) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482865/sliding-layer-activity-animation-android).